# how to set/add a background image in symfony

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony doctrine 1.4. I have a image picture and I was wondering how am I set this picture as a background image on my project(imagine of a website made up of pure html that has no background.. all white). I try to put my picture on the `web directory` and even I code this in a html format in the template layout `<body backgound = 'white5.jpg'>`. When I refresh my browser, nothing happened. Maybe because I don't know how to code it. Can someone guide me on how to set/add a background image using symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example you provided has a typo: `backgound` instead of `background` (mind the r).
If the image is in the root of your webserver, you should add a / in front of the URL to make it absolute.

Everything you put in your `/web` directory is publicly accessible. If you go to the url of the backgroundimage directly, can you see it?

(And are you aware of CSS?)

Comment: Honestly... I dont have any idea about css but thanks for the reply =)